# Looking for a French-Japanese dictionary in text format

Tags: resource-request, japanese, french

Does anyone know where I might be able to get hold of a French to Japanese dictionary in plain text format? I am not looking for a website or an app.

Comment: By "plain text format" you just mean a physical book, right?

Comment: Sorry, I meant something like .txt, I want to do some text processing on it.

Comment: I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a physical paperback/hardback book, then here are a few options:

- [DICTIONNAIRE STANDARD JAPONAIS FRANCAIS](https://www.amazon.fr/DICTIONNAIRE-STANDARD-JAPONAIS-FRANCAIS/dp/4469051411)
- [Maxi-poche plus japonais](https://www.amazon.fr/Maxi-poche-plus-japonais-Claude-Nimmo/dp/2035927250)
- [Harrap's Mini dictionnaire visuel Japonais](https://www.amazon.fr/Harraps-Mini-dictionnaire-visuel-Japonais/dp/2818705991)
- [Kanji et Kana : Manuel et lexique des 2141 caractères officiels de l'écriture japonaise suivi de caractères composés formant un vocabulaire de base de plus de 12 000 mots](https://www.amazon.fr/Kanji-Kana-caract%C3%A8res-officiels-vocabulaire/dp/2720012203)
- [Vocabulaire français-japonais pour l'autoformation. 9000 mots](https://www.amazon.fr/Vocabulaire-fran%C3%A7ais-japonais-pour-lautoformation-9000/dp/1783142405)
- [Le Dico: Dictionnaire Français-Japonais](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/456000028X)
- [Dictionnaire Japonais](https://www.amazon.fr/Dictionnaire-fran%C3%A7ais-japonais-japonais-fran%C3%A7ais-Assimil/dp/2700506014)

EDIT:

Probably the closest you'll find is [jibiki.fr](https://jibiki.fr/?lang=eng). It says that the results of that Japanese-French project are downloadable.